# tab stops in header: need 4 slots

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, header-footer

The header/footer usually allow for the "left", "center", and "right" slots. How does one implement more than 3 slots?

I'll try to distill my document to a minimal example and would amend this post then. But, perhaps, there is a general package or solution already known?

My efforts so far: I use `titleps` and `\sethead{...}{}{}` expanding the left slot across the whole header. However, the commands from the `tabto` package don't seem to work inside `\sethead`. So I'm now learning how to roll out my own tab stops with `\hfil` and so on, but I wonder whether I succeed to make it consistent and aligned within slots...

Comment: LaTeX does not think in terms of tab stops. But what's the problem with putting a box of width `\textwidth` in one header field and then dividing it in parts with `\parboxes` or something similar?

Comment: You may want to seriously reconsider whether it makes much sense to have four [4!] distinct items in the header line. Even with 3 items, it's usually necessary to abbreviate/shorten 1 or 2 of the items in order to make them all fit on a single line. With 4 distinct items on one line, the likelihood that the header line will amount to nothing but visual clutter is bound to rise sharply.

Comment: @Mico One of the header I had to implement has 24 slots in 4 lines ;-).

Answer (score 4):

The three slots are only there to make it easier to setup a header by offering "standard" locations. You can put in the header more or less whatever you want (perhaps you will have to adjust the \headheight):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\begin{tabular}{@{}*{5}{p{\dimexpr \textwidth/5}@{}}} 
        \leftmark & \rightmark & \thepage & 
        some nonsense &\hfill a logo \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}
\subsection{cde}
blblb
\newpage
blblb
\end{document}
```

[image]